# How to load multiple preload.js files in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, electron

[image: File structure]

How to export `preload1`, `preload2`, `preload3` and introduce them into index?

**index.ts**

```
const test1 = require("./preload1")
const test2 = require("./preload2")
const test3 = require("./preload3")
const { contextBridge } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('testApi', { test1, test2, test3 })
```

**preload1.ts**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

const test1 = async () => {
  return await ipcRenderer.invoke('on-test-event')
}

export default {test1}
```

**preload2.ts**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

const test2 = async () => {
  return await ipcRenderer.invoke('on-test-event')
}

export default {test2}
```

**preload3.ts**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

const test3 = async () => {
  return await ipcRenderer.invoke('on-test-event')
}

export default {test3}
```

**index.vue**

```
console.log(testApi);
```

Console error

```bash
VM4 sandbox_bundle:93 Unable to load preload script: \electron-vite-vue\dist-electron\preloads\index.js


VM4 sandbox_bundle:93 Error: module not found: ./preload1
    at preloadRequire (VM4 sandbox_bundle:93:1386)
    at <anonymous>:2:17
    at runPreloadScript (VM4 sandbox_bundle:93:2211)
    at Object.<anonymous> (VM4 sandbox_bundle:93:2478)
    at ./lib/sandboxed_renderer/init.ts (VM4 sandbox_bundle:93:2632)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM4 sandbox_bundle:1:170)
    at VM4 sandbox_bundle:1:1242
    at ___electron_webpack_init__ (VM4 sandbox_bundle:1:1320)
    at VM4 sandbox_bundle:160:455
```

If I write all the preload in the index, it works fine:

**index.ts**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

const test1 = async () => {
  return await ipcRenderer.invoke('on-test-event')
}

const test2 = async () => {
  return await ipcRenderer.invoke('on-test-event')
}

const test3 = async () => {
  return await ipcRenderer.invoke('on-test-event')
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('testApi', {test1, test2, test3})
```

Console

```bash
{test1: ƒ, test2: ƒ, test3: ƒ}
 test1: ƒ ()
 test2: ƒ ()
 test3: ƒ ()
 [[Prototype]]: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Electron's processes are [sandboxed](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox), which means that you can't use `require` in your renderer, and you can only `require` some [specific modules](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox#preload-scripts) in your preload (emphasis mine):

> In order to allow renderer processes to communicate with the main process, preload scripts attached to sandboxed renderers will still have a polyfilled subset of Node.js APIs available. A `require` function similar to Node's `require` module is exposed, **but can only import a subset of Electron and Node's built-in modules**: [...]

If you use a bundler, you should be able to use `import` statements for these files instead of `require`:

> Because the `require` function is a polyfill with limited functionality, you will not be able to use [CommonJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules_commonjs_modules) to separate your preload script into multiple files. If you need to split your preload code, use a bundler such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/).

However, if you really want/need to use `require`, you can only do it by disabling `sandbox` in the `webPreferences` of your [`BrowserWindow`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window):

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: false,
    contextIsolation: true,
    sandbox: false
  }
});
```

But don't forget that sandboxing is a security feature which is [not recommended to disable](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#4-enable-process-sandboxing).